# WordPress Woocommerce - Product Type

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have recently created a php script to import new products into Woocommerce. Please see how it was done here [How to add product in woocommerce with php code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137501/how-to-add-product-in-woocommerce-with-php-code/).

The question I have is related to the **product type**. When you add a new product in the backend you can choose the product type: *simple, grouped, external/affiliate, and variable product*.

When I create new products with the script it uses the simple product type by default and I cannot find anywhere in the woocommerce database where I can change the product type to *external/affiliate*. **Does anyone know where that data is stored for each product?**

I check and double checked the posts and postmeta tables and cannot find anything related to the product type. I attempted a search in the options table but cannot find anything either unless it's encoded in there.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: I can't really see why this could be off topic because woocommerce is built for WordPress and the issue I had was related to the way WordPress stores its data. It is resolved now, thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Products are Custom Post Types, so you can find it in wp_posts.post_type='product' || 'product_variation', etc.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am more specifically looking for data that uniquely identifies the product as an **external/affiliate** product. There are 4 types of products: simple, grouped, external/affiliate, and variable.

Comment: In this case, the info of each product line is in wp_woocommerce_order_items and order_itemmeta table.

Comment: Just to let you know about the product type in case you come across it someday. The product type is stored as a taxonomy term. The term is "external" and the taxonomy is "product_type". When you link that to a product, that product is used as an external/affiliate product. Thank you for your responses, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @josearcos that is wrong. That is the product type of orders, not of the actual products stored in the database. The last comment by Kobus Beets should be the accepted answer.