# How to put a date range in a virtual/downloadable product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've searched for this kind of situation, but couldn't find anything that can help me.
We're selling files with daily data (stock prices) on a woocommerce store, and I want something that I can put a date range (e.g 01/01/2016 - 31/12/2017) and have a dynamic price based on this range.
Then, I'd call a microservice to create the file for me and put it on the user's inventory.

Any ideias how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook into add_to_cart hook

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'create_files_for_cart');

function create_files_for_cart() {
 // Your code that created the file using the dated the user selected

 // More code to add the file created to cart

}
```

The code to create the downloadable file product is similar to the code in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137501/how-to-add-product-in-woocommerce-with-php-code)

Add the product to cart with the [Cart class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html) functions

You use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/) to add the date fields to the product.

Comment: Thanks! I'm already creating the plugin to make it
How about the date range? How can I make it so the user select two different dates, and it shows the total cost?

Comment: @fuyangli Iv'e added to the answer a plugin that could add date fields to the product page