# Woocommerce products are not displayed on front-end . No products were found matching your selection

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

> No products were found matching your selection.

This error appears only for non-admin users/guests on all category pages. But if I go to some product link directly, I can see the product page and add it to the cart.

I've already tried to change "default sorting" option.

The only way that I've found is to go to "Edit Product" and click "Update" button. Only after this action, this product will appear in shop. But it's not a solution cuz I have a script which import new products time by time and I can't click this button for 10000+ products.

Updated:

```
private function createProduct($product, $brand)
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $item = [
            'post_title' => $product['name'],
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'product'
        ];
        $postId = wp_insert_post($item);

        $meta_keys = [];
        $meta_keys['_visibility'] = 'visible';
        $meta_keys['_stock_status'] = 'instock';
        $meta_keys['wholesale_customer_wholesale_price'] = $product['wholesale_price'];
        $meta_keys['wholesale_customer_have_wholesale_price'] = $product['have_wholesale_price'];
        $meta_keys['_price'] = $product['price'];
        $meta_keys['_regular_price'] = $product['price'];
        $meta_keys['_weight'] = $product['weight'];
        $meta_keys['_sku'] = $product['sku'];
        $meta_keys['_stock'] = $product['stock_quantity'];
        $meta_keys['_manage_stock'] = 'yes';
        $meta_keys['_id_ds'] = $product['id_ds'];
        $meta_keys['_ean'] = $product['ean'];
        $meta_keys['_retail_price'] = $product['retail_price'];
        //$meta_keys['_product_attributes'] = maybe_serialize(wp_unslash($product['attributes']));;

        /* SET Attributes */
        $meta_keys['_product_attributes'] = maybe_serialize(wp_unslash($this->createAttributes($postId, $product['attributes'])));
        /* SET Attributes */

        $custom_fields = [];
        $place_holders = [];
        $query_string = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ";
        foreach($meta_keys as $key => $value) {
            array_push($custom_fields, $postId, $key, $value);
            $place_holders[] = "('%d', '%s', '%s')";
        }
        $query_string .= implode(', ', $place_holders);
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("$query_string ", $custom_fields));

        $this->generateFeaturedImage($product['image'], $postId);

        wp_set_object_terms( $postId, 'simple', 'product_type' );
        wp_set_object_terms($postId, get_term_by('name', $brand->name,'product_cat')->term_id, 'product_cat');

        //update_post_meta($postId, '_product_attributes', $product['attributes']);
        return $postId;
    }
```

Comment: Probably the problem is that script. What `post_status` this script applies to the imported products?

Comment: `$item = [
   'post_title' => $product['name'],
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'post_type' => 'product'
  ];
  $postId = wp_insert_post($item);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce products have a lot of metadata. Give a look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/137578/122788) to see most of them.

In your case it seems that the problem is the missing `_visibility`.

Did you already try something like this?

```
$item = [
    'post_title' => $product['name'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'product',
];
$postId = wp_insert_post($item);
update_post_meta( $postId, '_visibility', 'visible' );
```

Comment: nah, I pass visibility.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the complete code then, @ZhiV?

Comment: Everything was good before, I did some changes in categories and now I can't find the source of problem.

Comment: Just, admin can see the products and other users can not...

Comment: It's somehow connected with wholesale plugin

Comment: found the issue, my script needed `$meta_keys['wwpp_product_wholesale_visibility_filter'] = 'all';` option at least